# Couldn't parse date-time string with GMT mark with parse_date_time function

Tags: r, lubridate, gmt

I have data frame with dates columns in the following format: year, month, date, hour (24h), minute and GMT mark without separators ("201902011000GMT+3" as example) and try to convert it with parse_date_time function to date-time. I couldn't select right parameters for such string.

I try to use some orders:

```r
begin <- parse_date_time("201902011000GMT+3", orders = "YmdHMz")
begin <- parse_date_time("201902011000GMT+3", orders = "YmdHMz", tz = "GMT+3")
```

But have warning "All formats failed to parse. No formats found." and NA as a result.
Are there any ways to parse this string correctly with correct GMT?
Thank you.